# Why conversion from unsigned long long to double can lead to data loss?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, floating-point

When I compile this trivial piece of code via Microsoft's VC 2008:

```
double maxDistance(unsigned long long* a, unsigned long long* b, int n)
{
    double maxD = 0, currentD = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        currentD = b[i] - a[i];
        if(currentD > maxD)
        {
            maxD = currentD;
        }
    }
    return maxD;
}
```

The compiler gives me:

> warning C4244 stating: conversion from 'unsigned long long' to 'double', possible loss of data. On the line

```
currentD = b[i] - a[i]
```

I know that it's better to rewrite the code somehow, I use double to account for possible negative values of the difference, but I'm just curious, why in the world conversion from unsigned long long to double can lead to data loss if unsigned long long's range is from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 and double is
 +/- 1.7E +/- 308 ?

Comment: what if the value is `-3.2` converting it to `unsigned long long` would loose the `.2` and the `-`...

Comment: There are long long numbers which cannot be exactly represented as a double

Comment: The biggest **integer** you can represent in a double without losing digits off the low end is (about) 53 bits.

Comment: Do you *care* about the sign, or is it ultimately the *absolute-difference* of the two values (the distance between them) you're trying to retain the max of? If so, a little rearrangement to detect larger from smaller prior to computing said-distance (hello, ternary expression) would allow all of this to be reduced to just using `unsigned long long`

Comment: small sidenote : please use `UINT64` / `INT64` and similar macros as these are windows version - agnostic and WILL always represent your desired data type. Using primitives with MSVC will lead to problems one day - this is not linux, even primitives may (and will) be changed

Comment: @specializt Even better, use `uint64_t` which has been standardized **for 16 years** and works on any C99-compliant compiler, instead of just being “windows version - agnostic”.

Comment: yes, but if you want to write a _platform_-independent application C and C++ and most likely the wrong choice - there are more fitting languages for that kind of task (like Java)

Answer (score 18):

An IEEE double-precision floating point number has 53 bits of mantissa. This means that (most) integers greater than 2<sup>53</sup> can't be stored exactly in a double.

Example program (this is for GCC, use `%I64u` for MSVC):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long ull;

    ull = (1ULL << 53) - 1;
    printf("%llu %f\n", ull, (double)ull);

    ull = (1ULL << 53) + 1;
    printf("%llu %f\n", ull, (double)ull);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9007199254740991 9007199254740991.000000
9007199254740993 9007199254740992.000000
```

Comment: What you say about IEEE floating point is true but there is no requirement that an implementation of C/C++ use IEEE floating point.   Yes, most modern implementations do, but not all do.

Comment: @Rob You're right, but the question is about MSVC which, as far as I know, is only available on platforms that conform to IEEE 754.

Answer (score 3):

A `double` supports a larger range of possible values, but cannot represent all values in that range.    Some of the values that cannot be represented are integral values, which a `long` or a `long long` can represent.

Trying to assign a value into a floating point variable that it cannot represent means the result is some approximation - a value that is close, but not exactly equal.    That represents a potential data loss (depending on what value is being assigned).